# V versus P in an Adiabatic Process

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume, adiabatic

I have a question in which a gas undergoes a an expansion in such a way that the Pressure is a linear function of the volume on a V versus P diagram.
One of the professors I asked said that means an adiabatic process, but i'm not convinced why.

So far the web has been of little help, so please can anyone confirm this or explain why this is true?

thanks

Comment: If the curve was log(p) vs. log (V) then you would have a linear relationship for adiabatic (more correctly, isentropic) process.

Comment: very good point, I did not consider a log-log plot

Answer (score 1):

Adiabatic expansions (defined as a system that does not have any heat transfer) obey the following relationship $$ PV^{\alpha} = constant $$ where alpha is some characteristic constant. So, no, a straight line sloping down (it would be negative, because as a gas expands the pressure goes down, right?) it not possible given that exponential relationship on a linear graph.

Of course, on a log-log plot everything looks like a line, so perhaps that is what your professor was thinking

Comment: this is what I thought, it doesn't make sense for it to be adiabatic

Comment: but does the linear dependence have any other significance?

Comment: Yes.  It means that the temperature is controlled in such a way that the volume varies linearly with pressure.  So you need to be adding or removing just the right amount of heat to make this happen.

Comment: (on a linear graph) right, is not impossible, but you would have to transfer heat to the system to get a straight line sloping down